# regex in Notepad++ to remove blank lines

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have multiple html files and some of them have some blank lines, I need a regex to remove all blank lines and leave only one blank line..  So it removes anything more than one blank line, and leave those that are just one or none (none like in having text in them).

I need it also to consider lines that are not totally blank, as some lines could have spaces or tabs (characters that doesn't show), so I need it to consider these lines with the regex to be removed as long as it is more than one line..

Comment: AFAIK, notepad++'s regex patterns don't match multiple lines, which means you won't be able to reduce multiple lines down to one.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your text file?

Comment: Looked at TextFX menu -> TextFX Edit -> Delete surplus blank lines ?

Comment: @zzzzBov: The latest update should fix this (you need to select Perl regexes, though, as far as I know).

Comment: @TimPietzcker, where's the option to select Perl regexes?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, oh, nvm, running the updater once apparently wasn't enough to install the latest version, I've now got the option to match newlines.

Comment: Thanks guys..  the answers worked well..  re TextFX Edit, it works for one file only, and doesn't ignore spaces or tabs if they are in that page.

Comment: There's an easier way to do this that doesn't require regex: Edit > Line Operations > Remove empty lines (containing blank characters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Search for

```
^([ \t]*)\r?\n\s+$
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of line
([ \t]*)  # Match any number of spaces or tabs, capture them in group 1
\r?\n     # Match one linebreak
\s+       # Match any following whitespace
$         # until the last possible end of line.
```

`\1` will then contain the first line of whitespace characters, so when you use that as the replacement string, only the first line of whitespace will be preserved (excluding the linebreak at the end).

Comment: It should. I don't have Notepad++ installed, but that's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @MartinF: Care to elaborate? What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: Nothing happened when i tried it, but now on another puter, it works! (I tried to undo the downvote but it seems an edit is required. Maybe add an explanation for the "\1" replacement?

Comment: Back at original puter. It "partially works": Some blank line sequences get reduced to single blank lines, while many only get reduced to pairs of blank lines. Subsequent invocations --often required in simplistic reductions-- have no effect. There are many occurrences of "\r\n\r\n\r\n" that your regex  reduction has no effect upon. Doing a simple replace of "\r\n\r\n\r\n" with "\r\n\r\n" does then work. Strange.

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't any other characters in-between the whitespace characters (unprintable Unicode codepoints, for example)? I suppose NPP has a hex editor you could use to check?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me on `notepad++ v6.5.1. UNICODE windows 7`

Search for:  `^[ \t]*\r\n`

Replace with: *nothing, leave blank*

Search mode: `Regular expression.`

Answer (score 2):

search for `(\r?\n(\t| )*){3,}`, replace by `\r\n\r\n`, check "Regular expression" and ". matches newline".

Tested with Notepad++ 6.2

Answer (score 2):

This will replace the successive blank lines containing white spaces (or not) and replace it with one new line.

**Search for**
`(\s*\r?\n){3,}`

**replace with**
`\r\n`

Comment: Windows newlines are `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can find it yourself what you need to replace with 
\n\n OR \n\r\n or \r\n\r\n etc ... now you can even modify your regular expression `^([ \t]*)\r?\n\s+$` according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

I tested any of the above suggestions, always was either too less or to much deleted. So that either you got no blank line where at least one was beforehand or deleted not enough (whitespaces was left, etc.). Unfortunately I cannot write comments yet. Tested both with 6.1.5 and updated to 6.2 and tested again. depending on how mayn files there are, I would suggest use

```
Edit->Blank Operations->Trim trailing whitespace
```

Followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and

```
TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Delete surplus blank lines
```

A Macro I tried to record didn't work. Theres even a macro for just remove trailing whitespace (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, see Settings | Shortcut Mapper... | Macros). There's a

```
Edit->Blank Operations->Remove unnecessary EOL and whitespace
```

but that deletes every EOL and puts everything in a single line.

Comment: Thanks..  I was looking for regex as I need to do that operation in multiple files..  all these suggested menus in NP++ do that for only one file at a time, for the selected text only.. However, the first answer that I accepted does the trick..

Comment: @Mike The one you accepted didn't work for me and left -in case of mixed blank lines with and without whitespace- two blank lines instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for `^\r\n` and click "Replace All" with nothing (empty) in "Replace with" textbox.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ v8.4.7 there is the option:

Edit > Line Operations > Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank characters)

or

Edit > Line Operations > Remove Empty Lines

So there is no need to use a regular expressions for this. But this only works for one file at a time.

Comment: This will remove ALL the blank lines. They want to keep one of them.